# Suggestions for improving this little piece of code?

Tags: python

Any suggestions to improve this little piece of code? It works, but there must be a better way of doing it. Especially the first two lines, I have a bunch of them. Can't I merge the two somehow?

```
for iso in set(BAR_Items):
    if iso+YEAR in heights: 
        mylist.append(heights[iso+YEAR])
mylist.sort()
cut = percentile(mylist, POS)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first three lines can be written concisely as a list comprehension.

```
mylist += [heights[iso+YEAR] for iso in set(BAR_Items) if iso+YEAR in heights]
```